# Como saber se o email realmente foi enviado?

Tags: android, envio-de-email

Estou usando um código para o envio de e-mail, chamo o serviço de envio de e-mail e escolho um determinado e-mail que já está configurado no celular. Está tudo funcionando normalmente, porém eu quero colocar um *alert* após o envio desse e-mail mas não consigo exibir na hora certa, por não ter uma resposta positiva ou negativa do envio desse e-mail. Como eu faço para saber que o email realmente foi enviado? Segue o meu código...

```
                Intent sendEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, assunto);
                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{email});
                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "texto...");

                sendEmail.setType("message/rfc822");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser
                     (sendEmail, "Enviar o e-mail com: "));

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                alert.setTitle("Obrigado pelo contato !");
                alert.setMessage("texto...");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                alert.show();
```

Comment: Este código pode te ajudar


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471217/trivial-get-confirmation-of-email-sent-in-android

Answer (score 1):

A responsabalidade de informar se o email foi ou não enviado é da activity a qual sua intent invocou. Por isso não há necessidade de você tratar o caso de sucesso ou erro do envio do e-mail. Ela mesma informará o usuário caso a ação não seja completada com sucesso.

Comment: Sim eu concordo com você, porem nesse projeto sou obrigado a colocar esse feedback ao usuário.  será que é possível receber algum tipo de resultado dessa activity ?

Comment: Apenas se activity te repassar essa informação. E se for esse o caso, o modo de pegar essa informação estará na documentação dessa activity (site do desenvolvedor)

Comment: Eu já pesquisei muito sobre isso e não encontrei, devido eu invocar um aplicativo(fechado) que envia email ele não me retorna um true ou false do envio, pq nessa caso fico dependente do outro app.